# Rendering problems after updated gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, rendering, android-styles

I just updated build.gradle(Module: app) dependecies, and after that had rendering problems on Android Studio. What is wrong, before updating dependencies everythink worked correctly

Here is how it is now:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

**my_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/myPager"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    style="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout"
                    android:id="@+id/appTabs"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And got this error:

```
Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?      

Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  

The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  

Exception Details 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException   
    at
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:620)   
    at
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:108) 

Failed to find style with id 0x7fff00e4 in current theme (3 similar errors not shown)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clicking the option'Sync Project With Gradle Files':

*Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files*

If that fails, try running 'Rebuild project':

*Build -> Rebuild Project*