# Rendering problems with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rendering

Been a few times i've tryed working with Android Studio.

Each time that i've runned on the AVD my sample code it gives me a "Rendering problems" with a few specifications :

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 
>   Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use
>   a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy
>   stack to clipboard  Failed to find the style corresponding to the id
>   2147418374 (3 similar errors not shown)

I want to know why is this always occuring after i launch the emulator device ?

What can i do to solve this issue ?

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here in this question :

[Rendering problems after updated gradle dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208716/rendering-problems-after-updated-gradle-dependencies)

But stil, i'd like to know what all this means in the error message ...